# I want to built my own React UI library, how can I start?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I do have some components I use across my projects so I thought it was a good idea to build my own React UI lib, but how?

Do I create a SPA using CRA and start coding and listing the components on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it’s one way to start.

But if you want to publish it or organize it to have a better use of it, I suggest you use **Storybook** as your dev environment and **Jest** + **ESlint**.

There’s some boilerplates like [React AZap](https://github.com/wanderlima/react-azap) to help you with that.

I built React AZap to be an easy to use React UI lib boilerplate.
It uses **Storybook** and stories to organize your components, it has a component generator using **Plop**, tests with **Jest**+**Enzime** and styles with **styled-components**.

Try it out, it can save you time to start your lib ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using CRA won't help you, as you won't be running this project.
Creating a library of components is the same as creating any other npm package, the only difference is that it should export components instead of normal functions/objects.
There are plenty of guides online that you can consult if you want more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I haven't thought of publishing it as npm package, but it's the best thing to do for sure. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving [this guide a read](https://medium.com/hy-vee-engineering/creating-a-monorepo-with-lerna-yarn-workspaces-cf163908965d), which goes into the details for how to structure a multi-package UI component library. The code is included as well, so you should be able to clone to repository and get started.

Hope that helps!